# Storm Topology topology not processing after 2 or 3 days

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm, apache-storm-topology

I am Running a 3 node Storm cluster .We are submitting a topology with 10 workers and below are the toplogy details

### **Topology details:**

```
kafkaspout: 1 (with 10 kafka partions and 10 executors) 
no of bolt: 4 (with bolt1 - 30 executors,bolt2 - 50 executors, bolt3 - 80 executors and bolt4 has 100 executors)
kafka spout pending : 500 messages
```

We are processing 8 to 10 million data per day.Issue is Toplolgy is running only for  2 to 3 days after while we see some failed tuples in kafka spout and no messages are processed.When submitting a new toplogy it works fine but again in 2 or 3 days we see the same issue.Can someone get us an solution for this.below is my storm Configuration

### **Storm.yaml:**

```
worker.childopts: "-Xmx3072m -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit -server -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:+UseCompressedOops -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1 -XX:SurvivorRatio=6 -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly"
storm.zookeeper.servers:
     - "zoo1"
     - "zoo2"
     - "zoo3"
storm.zookeeper.port: 2181
ui.port: 9095
ui.host: uihost

nimbus.host: "nimbushost"
storm.local.dir: "/storm-logs"

supervisor.slots.ports:
   - 6700
   - 6701
   - 6702
   - 6703
   - 6704
   - 6705
   - 6706
   - 6707
   - 6708
   - 6709
```

Comment: Please post which Storm version you're using, and whether you're using storm-kafka or storm-kafka-client.

Comment: **kafka_2.9.1-0.8.2.1** & **apache-storm-0.9.4**  are the version that is been used .We are using storm-kafka

Answer (score 0):

Those are both extremely old versions. I'm not too familiar with Storm pre-0.10, but I'll link this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49138567/8845188, since the cases seem similar.

Note that unlike the other user who is on Storm 1.1.1, you are on a version where STORM-1750 is likely not fixed, so you should consider upgrading.

Comment: Thanks for u r help... Will try those steps and let u know the results